# HTML: a href "../subfolder"

Tags: html

So my file root D:// has 2 file, the index.html it self and img folder(however it is named as image instead)

So here's my code. 
(assume it has body and html :))

```
<div style="background: black url('../image/background1.png')"></div>
    <div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">
        <table style="width:800px;background-image:">
            <tr>
                <td><a href="www.google.com"><img src="../image/logo.png"/></a><td>
                <td><p align="right"><b> When strategy and chance meets, champions born</b></td>
            <tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

So here's the peculiar thing

1> The img src doesn't works (assume those file do exist in the right folder in D://)

2> The a href for google also doesnt work. It makes the progam goes D://www.google.com

Any help?

PS:
This file will create a div with img background (repeated). Inside the div is a table to store logo.

Comment: `<img src="image/logo.png"/>` & `<a href="http://google.com">`

Answer (score 2):

1) you do not need the .. just use 'images/background1.png'

2) you need http://

Comment: If your index.html file is at d:/ then you should be able to reference the file using 'filename.ext' if it's in a folder like d:/wordfiles/ the use 'wordfiles/filename.docx'

Comment: No I mean let's say the index.html is at D://Folder1 and the image is stored in D://Folder2 , Your suggested syntax wont work. I tried to manipulate it with ../Folder2/logo.png, but it also don't work. This what I meant. How should I fix this trouble?

Comment: Just retried this on my computer to make sure i'm not going crazy.
    <img src='../folder2/rock.jpg'></img>
Worked fine.

Comment: It is case sensitive if that helps.

Comment: Dammit. It's not here. (And I know it works before, on the same browser and computer :P) It seems that when I copy the link source of the logo png (the broken icon, i meant), it shows "file:///image/logo.png" instead "file:///D://image/logo.png